# How can I custom datepicker in the vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuetify.js, timepicker

I want to make datetimepicker like this :    https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/consulting-and-support. If you click "2 Hour Consulting Session", it will display datetimepicker like this : https://ibb.co/kHrbHTG. I want to make like that. But I don't find the component datetimepicker in the documentation. The docs : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers

Based on my analysis, it uses datepicker modal. not the datepimepicker. The timepicker is only customized using the outline button. but I am confused how to place the outline button next to the datepicker

My script like this :

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
      <v-dialog
        ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal"
        :return-value.sync="date"
        persistent
        width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on">Call datepicker</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
          <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
        </v-date-picker>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      modal: false,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible to customize the datepicker to be like that?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier to you: don't beg for answers in comments please. No one will read it anyway, unless they open the question in the first place. Please take the [tour] and remember we are volunteers under no obligation whatsoever to help you. If someone knows the answer and cares to share it, good for you, otherwise too bad. As mentioned earlier: if you get 75 reputation you can [place bounties on your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to attract more attention, which is the official way to attract attention.

Answer (score 0):

That Datepicker is not part of Vuetify. That screenshot you took is in fact an `<iframe>` of the https://calendly.com/ website, which looks like a website for managing appointments. So that calendar is basically just custom CSS made by that company, nothing to do with Vuetify.